# Rails 3 - acts_as_tenant with custom tenant ID column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, acts-as-tenant

Has anyone successfully used the Rails `acts_as_tenant` gem for multitenancy, where the tenant ID column is not named `xxx_id`?

my model is something like

```
has_one :tenant, :foreign_key => "tenant_code" 
acts_as_tenant :tenant
```

Then I get my query `select * from [table] where tenant_id = xxx` ignoring the overridden `foreign_key` spec.

Is there any way to fix this?  or am I doing something else obviously wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update to this issue for future reference:

From gem version 0.3.3 onwards it is now possible to explicitly set the foreign key.

```
acts_as_tenant(:account, :foreign_key => 'accountID')
```

Perhaps this helps someone who finds this question.

Answer (score 1):

ActsAsTenant sets it's own foreign key in the gem itself as (pseudocode) #{tenant_klass}_id:

```
def self.fkey
  "#{@@tenant_klass.to_s}_id"
end
```

https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/blob/master/lib/acts_as_tenant/model_extensions.rb#L12-L14

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can set your own foreign key for anything other than activerecord model relationships (with your code, you could still theoretically call model.tenant; however, that doesn't help you).